# Error on runing a raw iso on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, iso, cd

I have download a raw iso cd from the internet.
Try one: I'm import the iso on the vbox storage but when it boots i get "Fatal: no bootable device".
Try two: Convert the iso to vmdk with VBoxManage , imported to vbox storage but the error still exist.
Try three: Converted to vdi, imported to vbox storage but still the same. 
I also try the PowerIso for linux to converted the iso to another format and still nothing 
I found few solution in here but none of them works for me.
As i open the iso i found (3 *.swf) files inside and that makes me wonder about infected iso .... is any possibility on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set it up to read the ISO as a cd-rom device?

Comment: Already try it but nothing, but i want to ask is it possible that iso (with 3 .swf ) files to boot up